# PowerShell moving files based on dates

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move all files six months or older into an archive file 
I have

```
#set root folder
$baseFolder = "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop"
$archiveBase = "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop"
$limit_to=(Get-date (Get-date -Format d)).AddDays(-180)
#get files inside root
$folder = Get-ChildItem $baseFolder -File

#for each folder

foreach($file in Where-$folder.CreationTime -lt $limit_to ) {

    #build the move destination path
    $a=$file.CreationTime.Date.Year 
    $archive="Archive"
    $name=$a+" "+$archive
    $destination = Join-Path $archiveBase $name


    #Create Directory And Deposite Files
    if(Test-Path $destination)
    {
        mv $file $destination
    }
    else
    {
        mkdir $destination
        mv $file $destination
    }

}
```

I cant seem to get only the files that are older than 180 days.
I am a beginner so any efficiency changes I could make I'm open to

Comment: You can access the file's creation year via `((Get-ChildItem).CreationTime).Year`. Just include that appropriately into the destination path of `copy-item`.

Comment: alright sorry about that last mess that didn't make any sense i think you could fix my problem now @davidhigh

Comment: see if this helps http://blog.kandiaro.net/2016/08/uncategorised/powershell-move-files-older-given-days/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  $baseFolder = "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\"
  $archiveBase = "C:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\"
  $limit_to=(Get-date (Get-date -Format d)).AddMonths(-6)

  mkdir $archiveBase -force

  Get-ChildItem $baseFolder -File | where CreationTime -lt $limit_to | foreach {move-item $_.FullName -Destination ($archiveBase + $_.CreationTime.Year + " Archive" + $_.Name) -Force }
```